# Cross reference in Symfony2 form not work as expected

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

This is my first question here, so please excuse any mistakes - I'll try to avoid them the next time. ;-)

I've written a custom RegistrationFormType for the FOSUserBundle. This form handles - in addition to the default fields of the bundle - a PlayerType. This PlayerType itself again contains a PlayerSkillsType. Here the classes:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('player', new PlayerType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'signup_form';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\User',
        );
    }
}

class PlayerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname');
        $builder->add('lastname');
        $builder->add('age');
        $builder->add('playerSkills', new PlayerSkillsType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'player_form';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Player',
        );
    }
}

class PlayerSkillsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('tackling');
        $builder->add('passing');
        $builder->add('shooting');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'playerSkills_form';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\PlayerSkills',
        );
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Player
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PlayerSkills", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     * @var PlayerSkills
     */
    private $playerSkills;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PlayerSkills
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Player", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     * @var Player
     */
    private $player;
}
```

(I've left out getters and setters and unimportant properties and methods.)
This is working fine so far, the form is shown and persisted. Now, my problem is, that after persisting the data, the PlayerSkills entity in the data is missing the reference back to the Player entity.

I think it's something that I need to tell the PlayerSkillsType that it shall also add the reference in the form builder..? Or maybe this is issue in the Doctrine annotations?

Any hint is very appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could come from the initialization of your data and/or doctrine mapping.

The form will create the data_class if none is passed using `$form->setData`.
When you submit the form and bind data, It will call `$player>setPlayerSkills($playerSkill)`,
but it won't call $playerSkill->setPlayer($player);

Depending of the owning side of your oneToOne association, you should call one of the two methods so that Doctrine will be aware of this association ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side ).

Try to modify your annotation mapping in PlayerSkills to introduce the `inversedBy` information also ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional ).

It should be something like this:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Player", mappedBy="playerSkills", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @var Player
 */
private $player;
```

Same thing for the Player class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PlayerSkills", inversedBy="player" cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @var PlayerSkills
 */
private $playerSkills;
```

Last, you can code your methods to automatically synchronize inverse side, as explained here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#picking-owning-and-inverse-side .